# CreatedAtRoute can't find route matching supplied values

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am running into a problem with a .NET Core tutorial. It is written in .NET Core 2.2, but I want to use the current release 3.0.

This is also the only difference I can find in my setup vs the tutorial's.

The issue is as follows:
I have a HttpPost route with a CreatedAtRoute call in it, but that can't find the route it has to.
I always get this error when testing through Postman:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
...
```

But when checking through the debugger I see that everything goes fine, excpet for this line. So the new photo I want to upload is also added in Cloudinary and into the database.

The call I make is:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetPhoto", new {id = photo.Id}, photoToReturn);
```

This should find this route, in the same file:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPhoto")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPhoto(int id)
{
```

Is there anything I miss here? I haven't found any useful answer yet...

**Edit**: [public repo available](https://github.com/stijnpiron/DatingApp.git), when cloning and running this, I still get the same error...

**Edit 2**: in the meanwhile, the tutorial covered more topics and I have found this:
CreatedAtRoute that calls another Controller with:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser",new {Controller="Users",id=createdUser.Id}, userToReturn);
```

works, when trying to call a route inside the same controller, it fails, also with this one:

```
return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetMessage), new {Controller = "Messages", id = message.Id}, message);
```

To call this route in the same controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetMessage")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessage(int userId, int id)
```

Comment: Are you using `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`? If so, what does the call to `UseEndpoints` look like in your 3.0 version?

Comment: yes, I am. Currently it is: `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); });` but it also won't work with `endpoints.MapController()` (a solution I found elsewhere before)

Comment: Have you tried it with both `MapDefaultControllerRoute` _and_ `MapControllers`?

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but it works fine for me without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 
`[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPhoto")]`
Use:
`[HttpGet("/{id}", Name = "GetPhoto")]`

I was getting same error and i solved it by putting '/' before id.