# CreatedAtAction() Cannot Find Route with Matching Parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I am attempting to return a `CreatedAtAction()` result from within an ApiController "NotUnitsController" which indicates a route on a separate ApiController "UnitsController".

Everything works as expected until generating the `CreatedAtAction()` response. I am receiving the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

I am not sure what I am missing. I have tried to remedy the issue with the following:

- Verified the spelling of the route parameters on both controllers
- Attempted to provide a route name to the `[HttpGet]` in the `UnitsController` & reference that name from the `NotUnitsController`.
- Added a `/` to the `[HttpGet("/{unitKey}")]` route as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286013/createdatroute-cant-find-route-matching-supplied-values).

The `v1` portion of the routes are hard-coded. I found that it could be an issue with dynamic route versioning on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/558).

I am also able to perform GET requests against the UnitsController endpoint. Only the `CreatedAtAction()` response is failing.

Here are snippets of the two controllers in question.

NotUnitsController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/not-units/{notUnitsKey:guid}/units")]
public class NotUnitsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Guid notUnitsKey, Input unitInput)
    {
        // TODO: Create Unit
        var unitKey = Guid.NewGuid();

        return CreatedAtAction(actionName: nameof(UnitsController.Get),
                               controllerName: nameof(UnitsController),
                               routeValues: new { unitKey },
                               value: new { unitKey });
    }
}
```

UnitsController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/units")]
public class UnitsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{unitKey:guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Guid unitKey)
    {
        // TODO: Get Unit by key
        var unit = $"My Unit with Id: {unitKey}";
        return Ok(unit);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `nameof(UnitsController.Post)` as the `actionName` value, and `new { unitKey = unitKey }` as the `routeValues` value on your `CreatedAtAction` response.